# write game with java3d

Tags: java, 3d

I write this program but it has exception in line

```
group.addChild(tg);
```

but when i add

```
TransformGroup tg = new TransformGroup();
```

into the for loop block it runs with any problem please tell me it's reason.

Thanks.

this is my code

```
public BranchGroup Creat()
{
    BranchGroup group = new BranchGroup();
    TransformGroup tg = new TransformGroup();
    for(float x = 0.0f; x < 1.0f; x += 0.1f)
    {
         Transform3D td = new Transform3D();
         Vector3f vector3f = new Vector3f(x, x, x);             
         td.setTranslation(vector3f);
         tg.setTransform(td);
         tg.addChild(new Cone(0.05f, 0.1f));
         group.addChild(tg);             
   }



    return group;
}
```

this is it's exception

```
Exception in thread "main" javax.media.j3d.MultipleParentException: Group.addChild: child already has a parent
    at javax.media.j3d.GroupRetained.checkValidChild(GroupRetained.java:478)
    at javax.media.j3d.GroupRetained.addChild(GroupRetained.java:487)
    at javax.media.j3d.Group.addChild(Group.java:290)
    at t39.Draw.Creat(Draw.java:68)
    at t39.Draw.<init>(Draw.java:50)
    at t39.Main.main(Main.java:22)
```

Comment: 11 questions and no accepted answers... good luck

Comment: What's the exception?  Based on your "fix", I would assume (without knowing anything about the library) that each `TransformGroup` can only be added to a parent `BranchGroup` once.  As it stands, it looks like having `group.addChild(tg)` inside the for loop is pointless since it's only interacting with objects outside the loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The same element can't exist more than once in the scene graph. When you create a new `TransformGroup` within the loop it doesn't break the rule, but if you don't create a new one for every `addChild()` you break this rule.

(There are exceptions to the "only once in the graph", via weaker references instead of parent/child, e.g. for attributes)